# Get Google Spreadsheet by Name instead of ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to import data from another spreadsheet and found the working code below. How do I retrieve the file by name instead of ID?

(The file ID changes every month, but the file name will be kept the same.)

```js
function ImportRange() {


var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx').
  getSheetByName(‘xxx').getRange('A1:D100').getValues();
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
                .getRange( 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length )
                .setValues(values);

}
```

Comment: probably the best way is that each time you create the spreadsheet, you note its ID somewhere. There is no guarantee that a filename will be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with iterating through spreadsheets with DriveApp to get them all and then compare them by name:

```
/* 
The function will iterate through spreadsheets in a given folder and return DriveApp file object (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)
folderId — string — the id of the folder to search for the target spreadsheet; root folder will be used if nothing is passed
targetSpreadsheetName - string - the name of the spreadsheet to be found
*/
function getSpreadsheet(folderId, targetSpreadsheetName) {
  var folder = folderId ? DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId) : DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var spreadsheets = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (spreadsheets.hasNext()) {
    var spreadsheet = spreadsheets.next();
    if (spreadsheet.getName() === targetSpreadsheetName) {
      return spreadsheet.getId();
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then in your `ImportRange` function you would use it this way:

```
function ImportRange() {
var id = getSpreadsheet('', 'Untitled spreadsheet'); //this way you'd get a spreadsheet named 'Untitled spreadsheet' in your root folder
if (id === null) return 'No spreadsheet';
var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id). 
  getSheetByName('xxx').getRange('A1:D100').getValues();
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
                .getRange( 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length )
                .setValues(values);

}
```

This function seems rather slow, though (it took the script around 1 sec to iterate over 1 spreadsheet in my case), and I wouldn't recommend running it every time you run `Import range`. If your target spreadsheet's id changes every month, it would be more reasonable to store it somewhere — in a technical spreadsheet or [document/script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) — and get it from there. Thus you'd need to run `getSpreadsheet` only once a month with an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).